# Is there a Java annotation to generate parameter documentation?

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc, embedded-documents

Projects like hadoop have a ton of [parameters](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml), but all that documentation is manually generated from xml, rather than coming from the [code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/c1d50a91f7c05e4aaf4655380c8dcd11703ff158/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/MRJobConfig.java).

Is there a way of doing something with an annotation that can generate this documentation?

```
  public static final String MAP_SORT_SPILL_PERCENT = "mapreduce.map.sort.spill.percent";

  <name>mapreduce.map.sort.spill.percent</name>
  <value>0.80</value>
  <description>The soft limit in the serialization buffer. Once reached, a
  thread will begin to spill the contents to disk in the background. Note that
  collection will not block if this threshold is exceeded while a spill is
  already in progress, so spills may be larger than this threshold when it is
  set to less than .5</description>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @param javadoc tag to generate parameter information in the code, such as [this example from the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc):

```
/**
 * Short one line description.                           
 *
 * @param  variable Description text text text.         
 * @return Description text text text.
 */    
public int methodName (...) {
    // method body with a return statement
}
```

That's how Oracle generates the official doc for Java [(example)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long))

Comment: That's a parameter to a function, this is an external parameter to a program.

Comment: same rules apply, right?  You can still put javadoc on your main() method using the @param annotation.  If that's not what you're looking for, can you clarify the question more?